# enabling SSL for Hyperledger Fabric couchdb

Tags: ssl, couchdb, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, couchdb-2.0

I want to use couchDB(V. 2.3.1) with SSL enabled, so I added [ssl] part to `/opt/couchdb/etc/local.d/docker.ini` file as shown below:

```
[ssl]
port = 6984
enable = true
cert_file = /etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls/server.crt
key_file = /etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls/server.key
cacert_file = /etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls/ca.crt

[daemons]
httpsd = {couch_httpd, start_link, [https]}

[admins]
Admin = ...

[couchdb]
uuid = ...
```

but i can't access the webUI with https! having this error:

```
This site can’t provide a secure connection
"IP" uses an unsupported protocol.
ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH
Unsupported protocol
The client and server don't support a common SSL protocol version or cipher suite.
```

this is the logs:

```
[error] 2020-05-17T06:52:18.046389Z nonode@nohost <0.19077.3> -------- SSL: hello: tls_handshake.erl:127:Fatal error: handshake failure - malformed_handshake_data

[error] 2020-05-17T06:52:18.046426Z nonode@nohost <0.18899.3> -------- application: mochiweb, "Accept failed error", "{error,{tls_alert,\"handshake failure\"}}"
[error] 2020-05-17T06:52:18.046508Z nonode@nohost <0.18899.3> -------- CRASH REPORT Process  (<0.18899.3>) with 0 neighbors exited with reason: {error,accept_failed} at mochiweb_acceptor:init/4(line:75) <= proc_lib:init_p_do_apply/3(line:247); initial_call: {mochiweb_acceptor,init,['Argument__1','Argument__2',...]}, ancestors: [https,couch_secondary_services,couch_sup,<0.202.0>], messages: [], links: [<0.253.0>], dictionary: [], trap_exit: false, status: running, heap_size: 1598, stack_size: 27, reductions: 954
```

can somebody please help me?

Comment: try using a reverse-proxy tool like `Traefik` infront of it. Let couchdb run on http and don't expose the couchdb port.  AFAIK, you can't use self-signed certs in browser. Browser not gonna recognize it hence try using Let'sEncypt with `Traefik` or any other Reverse Proxy tool.

This work iff the end goal is to open couchdb UI on a browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution and wrote a post about it:

https://medium.com/@pouyashojaei85/enabling-ssl-for-docker-couchdb-container-127388eca1a8